# How to prove $-\sqrt a < x<\sqrt a$ from $x^2<a$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, inequality

I want to prove the following:

> \begin{align}
> x^2<a \iff \tag 1 \\
> -\sqrt a < x<\sqrt a \tag 2
> \end{align}
>   Update:
>
> Do I need some  restriction on $a$ or is $a\in\mathbb R$?
>
> Between $(1)$ and $(2)$, is it correct to use "equivalence" or is it just "implies"?

My attempt:

Case 1: $x>0$:

We have 
\begin{align}
x^2&<a\iff \tag 3\\
\sqrt{ x^2} &<\pm \sqrt a \tag 4
\end{align}
But $\sqrt{ x^2}=\lvert x \rvert$? This looks weird?

Case 2: $x<0$.

If $x<0$ then $-x>0$ is positive, so
\begin{align}
(-x)^2=x^2&<a \iff \tag 5\\
x&<\pm \sqrt a \tag 6
\end{align}

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$ shouldn't look weird.  It's correct.  After all $\sqrt{(-13)^2} = |-13| = 13$.

Comment: You do need a restriction on $a$: it must be $\ge 0$.

Comment: Why are you  writing the $\pm$ in $\sqrt{x^2} < \pm a$?  $\sqrt{x^2} \ge 0$ and $-\sqrt{a} \le 0$ zero (if it exists at all).  So $\sqrt{x^2} < -\sqrt{a}$ is not possible and not relevent.  You might as well so $x< \sqrt{a}$ or $x < -\sqrt{a}$ or $x < -59$ or $x > 570,000$.  The "or"s don't add anything and might be false and if they are true the don't have to be.

Comment: You take it for granted that if $0 < m < n$ then $\sqrt{m} < \sqrt{n}$.  Is this a Word of God truth you were given or is it something that had to have been verified at some point.

Comment: The restriction to $a>0$ is implicit.

Answer (score 1):

For $a\le0$ the inequality has not solutions then for $a>0$ we have that

$$x^2<a \iff x^2-a<0 \iff (x-\sqrt a)(x+\sqrt a)<0$$

that is

- $x<-\sqrt a\quad \land \quad x>\sqrt a$

which is impossible or

- $x>-\sqrt a\quad \land \quad x<\sqrt a$

that is indeed

$$-\sqrt a<x<\sqrt a$$

Answer (score 0):

Write $$x^2-\sqrt{a}^2<0$$ and the use the formula $$a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$$

Answer (score 0):

From

$$x^2<a,$$ by taking the square root, a monotonic function, you get

$$\sqrt{x^2}=|x|<\sqrt a.$$

Writing $|x|<\pm a$ just doesn't make sense.

Now, if $x\ge 0$, then $$|x|=x<\sqrt a,$$

and if $x\le 0$, then

$$|x|=-x<\sqrt a.$$

Grouping these results,

$$(x\ge0\land x<\sqrt a)\lor(x\le 0\land -\sqrt a<x)$$ can be simplified to $$-\sqrt a<x<\sqrt a.$$

Comment: Hi, thanks! You use $x=0$ for both cases, can we do that? Shouldn't we have $(x\ge0\land x<\sqrt a)\lor(x<0\land -\sqrt a<x)$? I also updated my question, if we need some restriction for $a$ and if it is correct to use the equivalence-sign.

Comment: @JDoeDoe: there is no problem using the symmetric form.

Answer (score 0):

Take square roots of both sides in the inequality $$x^2< a$$ to get $$|x|<\sqrt a.$$ This is permissible provided the original inequality is true, which would automatically imply that $0\le a.$

Now $|x|=\pm x,$ depending on the sign of $x.$ Thus, if $x$ is positive, then the last inequality becomes $x<\sqrt a.$ And if $x\le 0,$ then the inequality is $-x<\sqrt a,$ or that $x>-\sqrt a.$ Combining these inequalities gives the result.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do you know that $0 < m < n$ means $\sqrt{m} < \sqrt{n}$?  Can you take that as a given.  If so, can you take for $m>0, n> 0$ then $m< n \iff \sqrt{m} < \sqrt{n}$ is a given?

In general:  You have an axiom that if $a < b$ and $c > 0$ then $ac < bc$. (as well as if $a < b$ then $a+d < b+d$

From that you can prove many propositions including i) if $a > 0$ then $-a < 0$; ii) if $a<b$ and $c < 0$ then $ac > bc$ and that iii) $x^2 = 0$ if $x=0$ and $x^2 > 0$ if $x \ne 0$, iv) if $a > 0$ there are two $x_0, x_1$ so that $x_i^2 = a$.  $x_0 > 0$ and $x_1 = -x_0 <0$; we call $x_0 := \sqrt{x_0}$ and $x_1=-\sqrt a$.  v) $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$.  $|x| =x$ if $x\ge 0$ and $|x|=-x$ if $x \le 0$. etc. These are basic I won't go over them but I think it worth pointing out that

For $a > 0; b> 0$ then 1)  $a < b \iff a^n < b^n\iff \sqrt[k]a < \sqrt[k]b$ for all $n,k \in \mathbb N$, is worth noting why it is true.

$a < b \implies a^2 = a*a < a*b < b*b < b^2$ and so by induction if $a^{n-1} < b^{n-1}$ then $a^n = a^{n-1}*a < b^{n-1}*a < b^{n-1}*b = b^n$.  And if $a \ge b$ then the same argument shows $a^n \ge b^n$ and so $a<b \iff a^n < b^n$.  And therefore $\sqrt[k]a < \sqrt[k]b \iff a=(\sqrt[k]a)^k< (\sqrt[k]b)^k = b \iff a^n < b^n$.

...

Okay, now we can *begin*:

To prove $x^2 < a \implies -\sqrt a < x <\sqrt a$.

$x^2 \ge 0$ so $a > 0$.  So $\sqrt a$ exists and $\sqrt a > 0$.

$x^2 \ge a$ so $\sqrt{x^2}=|x| > \sqrt a \ge 0$

If $x \ge 0$ we have $0 \le x=|x| = \sqrt{x^2} < \sqrt a$.

... and so $-\sqrt a < 0 \le x < \sqrt a$.

If $x < 0$ we have $0 \le -x=|x| =\sqrt{x^2} < \sqrt a$ and therefore:

$-\sqrt a < -\sqrt{x^2} = -|x| = x < 0$.

.... and so $-\sqrt a < x < 0 < \sqrt a$.

In either case we have $-\sqrt a < x < \sqrt a$.

...

to prove $-\sqrt a < x < \sqrt a\implies x^2 < a$.

(Note: if $\sqrt a$ exists at all, that means $a \ge 0$.)

If $x \ge 0$ then $0 \le x < \sqrt a$ and so $x^2 < (\sqrt a)^2 = a$

If $x < 0$ then $-\sqrt a < x < 0$ means $0 < -x < \sqrt a$.  And so $x^2 = (-x)^2 < (\sqrt a)^2 = a$.

Either way, $x^2 < a$.